# .NET 2.0 - Creating an interface to allow for editing/adding to be handled by the object itself?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have this code structure:

```
public abstract class ContentEntryBase
{
    public string UniqueIdentifier;
    public string Title;

    public abstract ContentType contentType { get;}
}

public class TextArticle : ContentEntryBase
{
    // Holds plain / HTML text as content

    public override ContentType contentType { 
        get { return ContentType.TextArticle; } }
}

public class Series : ContentEntryBase
{
    // Holds a series of TextArticles, Separators 
    // and Prefaces as content

    ContentEntryBase[] Articles = null;

    public override ContentType contentType { 
        get { return ContentType.Series; } }
}
```

ContentEntryBase isn't an interface as so to allow me to perform basic actions valid to all descendant types from the base class.

I have a WinForms application utilizing these classes, and I want it to be able to call a method on ContentEntryBase (meaning, without realizing the exact type of the object at hand) for both displaying the content, and editing it.

So for example, TextArticle would show a TextBox / WYSIWYG editor when accessed for editing, and return a string when accessed for display. When Series is accessed for editing, it would show a list of all elements it contains (derived from ContentEntryBase) where those items could be edited or sorted. When accessed for display, it would show a list of all children.
I also have several more derived types, but these are the basic ones.

I tried thinking of the best contract to define for this, but came with no good solution. Can this be made in a way where it could be used in both WinForms and WebForms or MVC? Can display and edit functionalities use the same contract / function (GetContent() or something)?

I know using .NET 2.0 only limiting this even further, but this is what I have to use...

Thanks in advance!

Itamar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just have an abstract `ShowEditor` method on ContentEntryBase.

```
public class TextArticle : ContentEntryBase
{
    public override void ShowEditor ()
    {
        var editor = new FrmTextEditor (this);
        editor.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

where the `FrmTextEditor` CTor takes an instance of `TextArticle` which it will modify and provides the UI to do such a thing?

The other option I can think of is to provide method which returns a `UserControl` which provides the same UI functionality.

**Edit **

Re-reading for display - assuming you are turning it all into text you could just have a method which returns a `List<string>` which is populated as required `TextArticle` would only have a single string in the collection and others could have multiple of them. You could even create some form of `DisplayObject` which wraps the string and provides additional data for you to use when displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good solution for this. WPF makes this kind of thing possible, but you're stuck in 2.0. But even with WPF, it's a non-trivial app to write.

Comment: How would the solution with WPF look like?

Comment: Like I said, it's non trivial. I wrote code that edited arbitrary (though must meet certain criteria) objects, and it took a couple weeks, and it's far from perfect.